# Can I get hold of malicious npm packages?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, node.js, vulnerability-management, npm

the npm [advisories site](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories) lists quite a lot of malicious packages which - in my understanding - are not packages with vulnerabilities but malicious per se. These packages were removed from the npm repo for good reason, but is there a possibility to get hold of these packages without being an AV-Company?

Comment: Try GitHub? Most NPM packages are open-source.

Comment: Malicious and/or vulnerable packages are contained within that repository.